# React add comma one single string

Tags: reactjs, division

I am using react app. I fetched one data from [open api](https://sampleapis.com/recipes/api/recipes). in that api the ingredient in one single string but divided by `\n1`. When I fetched the data it came like this one single string and the `\n1` shows like  `(, divided)`. I wanted to put the ingredients in the `ul li` elements or and `comma-a` after each ingredient. I tried lots of ways to split the data and also tried to add a comma after each word but it did not work. I shared my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-ride-6qb9j?file=/src/App.js).

**This is my code**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://sampleapis.com/recipes/api/recipes");
    const data = await response.json();

    setState(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((recipe) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div key={recipe.id}>
              <h1>{recipe.title}</h1>
              <p>{recipe.ingredients}</p>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I found my solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790745/how-to-wrap-comma-separated-values-string-in-single-quotes)'s question.

Answer (score 0):

try to split and mapping them in separate html elements

```
 <div className="App">
      {state.map((recipe) => {
        return (
          <div key={recipe.id}>
            <h1>{recipe.title}</h1>
            <div>{recipe.ingredients?.split("\n").map(ingre=><p>{ingre}</p>)}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: I edited the answer and I tried it inside the sandbox you provided @krisna

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and did it like this:

```js
const ingre = newRecipe.ingredients // this is the data
  var result = ingre.split(',')
    .map(word => `${word.trim()}`)
    .join(', ');
```